# Use rows in a dataframe as inputs for function and visualization

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Please help me iterate over each row of the following .CSV file, loaded as a Pandas dataframe called **df_data** in my subsequent code:

```
aud,wllt_cnt,bcr
Group A,64700,0.15116928389684975
Group B,7654,0.02786525362332031
Group C,11183,0.01278621197465396
Group D,8025,0.00881753794562903
```

Currently, I created the following function by providing references to specific locations (please refer to variables ***total_group_size*** and ***crc***):

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.stats.api as sms
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Group A
# making a dataframe that captures the combinations of holdout / lift
def expand_grid(data_dict):
    rows = itertools.product(*data_dict.values())
    return pd.DataFrame.from_records(rows, columns=data_dict.keys())

# making a function for testing
def test(holdout,lift):
    cl = 0.9
    alpha = 1-cl
    total_group_size = df_data.iloc[0,1]
    wllt_cnt_reach = total_group_size*0.6
    crc = df_data.iloc[0,2]
    conversion_rate_control = crc
    conversion_rate_test = conversion_rate_control*(1+lift)
    es = sms.proportion_effectsize(conversion_rate_test, conversion_rate_control)
    n1 = wllt_cnt_reach*(1-holdout)
    n2 = wllt_cnt_reach*holdout
    return sms.NormalIndPower().solve_power(es, nobs1=n1, alpha=alpha, ratio=n2/n1, alternative='two-sided')

holdout=np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5])
lift=np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.025, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.1, 0.125, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4])

df = expand_grid({'holdout':holdout,'lift':lift})
```

Then applying the function row-wise:

```
df['power'] = df.apply(lambda x:test(x[0],x[1]),axis=1)
```

And plotting a heatmap (here I also used reference to the **df_data** dataframe when giving a plot title (please refer to ***plt_title***):

```
plt_title = df_data.iloc[0,0]
x_axis_labels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
y_axis_labels = [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12.5, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (13,6))
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df.pivot(index='lift',columns='holdout',values='power'),
            annot=True, fmt='.0%', cmap=sns.color_palette("RdYlGn", 200), xticklabels=x_axis_labels, yticklabels=y_axis_labels,
            cbar_kws={'label': 'Power'})
fig.axes[0].invert_yaxis()
ax.set_title(plt_title)
plt.xlabel("Holdout")
plt.ylabel("% Lift")
b, t = plt.ylim() 
b -= 0.5
t += 0.5
plt.ylim(b, t)
plt.show()
```

I need to optimize this code, so that I don't have to copy-paste the same code to apply it to each row of the **df_data** dataframe. My understanding is that I need to change the function ***test*** from above to take more inputs, then wrap the plotting into another function and show a heatmap for each of the groups (rows in my .CSV file), but I'm stuck at the first step in this action plan.

Please help me take this off, and thank you in advance!